# UICollectionViewCell changes data as soon as scrolling begins

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a full page UICollectionViewCell and as soon as scrolling begins the data for the next indexPath gets printed. This is causing problems in my project because even if it is barely dragged at all the next indexPath gets printed and I have a UIButton inside of my UICell that I want to be hidden as soon as it is pressed. However I only want it to be hidden in that specific cell. For some reason it is now being hidden in different indexes of my collectionView. Anything will help thank you.

```
  class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


       init() {
       super.init(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
              }
       required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
          fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
              }

private var collectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    return collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0

    self.collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
    if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    }
    collectionView?.register(PostCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
}

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
       let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
       return screenSize

   }

      override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                  return itemsArr.count
           }

  var totalPrice = Double()

    @objc func buttonPressed(_ sender : UIButton){
    let item = itemsArr[sender.tag].price
    totalPrice += Double(item) ?? 0
    sender.isHidden = true
    print(item)
    print(totalPrice)
}

           override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! PostCell

    let item = itemsArr[indexPath.row]
    cell.set(name: item.name, brand: item.brand, price: item.price)
    cell.myButton.tag = indexPath.row

    cell.myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside) 
      return cell
  }
 }
```

Comment: In my opinion, you should use delegate for buttonPressed, when user pressed button you could get index cell and update data of cell in "itemArr" ( add var "isHidden" in obj item). After update your data completed you should reload collectionview or reload cell.

Comment: Use could try cell.myButton.isHidden = item.isHidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to maintain a set of row indices for which the button is hidden. Then when rendering the cell, if that row index is present in `hiddenRows`, then you hide the button before returning the cell.

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    private var hiddenRows = Set<Int>()

    init() {
        super.init(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private var collectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        return collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0

        self.collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
        if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        }
        collectionView?.register(PostCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
        return screenSize

    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return itemsArr.count
    }

    var totalPrice = Double()

    @objc func buttonPressed(_ sender : UIButton){
        hiddenRows.insert(sender.tag)
        let item = itemsArr[sender.tag].price
        totalPrice += Double(item) ?? 0
        sender.isHidden = true
        print(item)
        print(totalPrice)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! PostCell

        let item = itemsArr[indexPath.row]
        cell.set(name: item.name, brand: item.brand, price: item.price)
        cell.myButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
           print(item)
        if hiddenRows.contains(indexPath.row) {
            cell.myButton.isHidden = true
        } else {
            cell.myButton.isHidden = false
        }

        return cell
    }
 }
```

Comment: it gives me 'Protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'Hashable' because only concrete types can conform to protocols' on  private var hiddenRows: Set = []

Comment: Wait let me look into it. But do you get the concept?

Comment: My mistake. Sets are created differently. This should work now.

Comment: I will save the row indices for the cells, and if the row indice saved is present in hiddenRows, the button will be hidden, is what I understand from this. But is this still a problem for me why as soon as scrolling begins the data that gets printed changes?

Comment: What do you mean by data that gets printed changes?

Comment: I have    print(item) inside of cellForItemAt and for some reason each time even slight scrolling begins, the print statement prints the next item. Even if I am on the same cell.

Comment: also after doing this, it still remains hidden in the fourth and fifth indexes. There is a total of 5 index's

Comment: That is because the cellForRowAt for the next cell gets called as it starts to appear on screen.

Comment: Still remains hidden?

Comment: yes if I press the button on first index, fourth index is hidden, if I press it on second index, fifth gets hidden.